# Photoshop javascript batch replace smart layer from folder and resize

Tags: javascript, css, photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-script

I am trying to work out how to use javascript with photoshop, but eventhough i dont find a logical error in the code, it doesnt work properly.

I have a folder of 1000+ images/.ai files that have varying dimensions. I need these images on the Pillow and saved as .jpeg.
I choose the smartlayer and run the script to choose the images and it saves them correctly. The only problem is, that the resizing of images and positioning dont work properly.
If i put the image in manually, it works without issues, but not with the script.

If the width is greater than the height, it should set the width to 1200 px and calculate the height according to that. (and vice versa) and place in the middle of the layer.

1. How do i fix the resizing and positioning?
2. Is it possible to choose a folder where the images are inside instead of selecting the images?
3. How do i handle it when there are 2 smart layers to change in the mockup instead of 1?

Anyone know where the problem lies this code?
Im grateful for any bit of help!

```
 // Replace SmartObject’s Content and Save as JPG
// 2017, use it at your own risk
// Via @Circle B: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92796/replacing-a-smart-object-in-bulk-with-photoshops-variable-data-or-scripts/93359
// JPG code from here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/737789

#target photoshop
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
    var theName = myDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
    var thePath = myDocument.path;
    var theLayer = myDocument.activeLayer;
    // JPG Options;
    jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();  
    jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;  
    jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;  
    jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;  
    jpgSaveOptions.quality = 8;   
    // Check if layer is SmartObject;
    if (theLayer.kind != "LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT") {
        alert("selected layer is not a smart object")
    } else {
        // Select Files;
        if ($.os.search(/windows/i) != -1) {
            var theFiles = File.openDialog("please select files", "*.psd;*.tif;*.jpg;*.ai", true)
        } else {
            var theFiles = File.openDialog("please select files", getFiles, true)
        };
};
(function (){
    var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;  
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;  
    var bounds = activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;  
    var height = bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value;
    var width = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value;
if (height > width){ 
    var newSize1 = (100 / width) * 800;  
    activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(newSize1, newSize1, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;  
    }  
else{
    var newSize2 = (100 / height) * 800;  
    activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(newSize2, newSize2, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;      
    } 
})();
        if (theFiles) {
            for (var m = 0; m < theFiles.length; m++) {
                // Replace SmartObject
                theLayer = replaceContents(theFiles[m], theLayer);
                var theNewName = theFiles[m].name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
                // Save JPG
                myDocument.saveAs((new File(thePath + "/" + theName + "_" + theNewName + ".jpg")), jpgSaveOptions, true,Extension.LOWERCASE);
            }
        }
    };
// Get PSDs, TIFs and JPGs from files
function getFiles(theFile) {
    if (theFile.name.match(/\.(psd|tif|jpg)$/i) != null || theFile.constructor.name == "Folder") {
        return true
    }
};
// Replace SmartObject Contents
function replaceContents(newFile, theSO) {
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = theSO;
    // =======================================================
    var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(newFile));
    var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
    desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
    executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
    return app.activeDocument.activeLayer
};
```

I have attached 2 pictures. 1 how it needs to look like and 2 what the script outputs
[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qufui.jpg)
[Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lHTM.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand, why do you change size of your active document with the pillow instead of changing the size of opened files?

Comment: I thought i was doing that by resizing the layer the images get placed on? I didnt know of a better way to refer to the opened file... how do i do that?
I apologize, im not that experienced with javascript yet...

Comment: Resizing a smart object when it's modified in perspective may be difficult, I think it'd be easier to modify the files you need to put it. I see at least two ways of doing that: 1) opening all files and modifying their size so it'd be the same as SO, saving them to temp folder, replaceContent with those modified versions, exporting; 2) opening all files, modifying their size so it'd be the same as SO, duplicating them to SO, saving it, exporting

Comment: If i take out the resizing and just use the rest of the code, it still doesnt adjust to the perspective(https://www.imagebanana.com/s/1208/Hlc5MAdP.html). any idea how to solve that?

Comment: it won't adjust perspective for you, your pasted images should be the same size as original smart object, that's what I said in previous comment. This way your code works: http://prntscr.com/l5akp8

Answer (score 0):

1. Your replaced images have to be the same resolution as the smart object.
2. You can declare the folder path in your code. If you still want to select the path by hand, you can select one image in the path, and extract the parent folder path.
3. You can recursively go through all of the layers in the documents and extract all the smart objects that you want to replace.

You may want a function to recursively traverse all the layers in the document

```
function browseLayer(layer, fn) {
    if (layer.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < layer.length; ++i) {
            browseLayer(layer[i], fn)
        }
        return;
    }

    if (layer.layers) {
        for (var j = 0; j < layer.layers.length; ++j) {
            browseLayer(layer.layers[j], fn);
        }
        return;
    }
    //apply this function for every layer
    fn(layer)
}
```

Get all the smart objects in the document

```
const smartObjects = [];
//The smart objects can be visit twice or more
//use this object to mark the visiting status
const docNameIndex = {};

const doc = app.open(new File("/path/to/psd/file"));

browseLayer(doc.layers, function (layer) {
    //You cannot replace smart object with position is locked
    if (layer.kind == LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT && layer.positionLocked == false) {

        smartLayers.push(layer);

        doc.activeLayer = layer;

        //open the smart object
        executeAction(stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerEditContents"), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO);

        //activeDocument is now the smart object
        const docName = app.activeDocument.name;

        if (!docNameIndex[docName]) {

            docNameIndex[docName] = true;

            smartObjects.push({
                id: layer.id,
                name: layer.name,
                docName: docName,
                width : app.activeDocument.width.as('pixels'),
                height : app.activeDocument.height.as('pixels'),
                resolution : app.activeDocument.resolution //important
            });
        }
        //reactive the main document
        app.activeDocument = doc;
    }

});
```

I assume that you have two smart objects needed to replace, the images for replacement are stored in different folders with the same name.

```
smartObjects[0].replaceFolderPath = "/path/to/folder/1";
smartObjects[1].replaceFolderPath = "/path/to/folder/2";
//we need temp folder to store the resize images
smartObjects[0].tempFolderPath = "/path/to/temp/folder/1";
smartObjects[1].tempFolderPath = "/path/to/temp/folder/2";
```

Ex: The first iteration will replace `smartObjects[0]` with `"/path/to/folder/1/image1.jpg"`, and `smartObjects[1]` with `"/path/to/folder/image1.jpg"`

Now resize all the images following the properties of the smart objects

```
smartObjects.forEach(function(smartObject){

    //Get all files in the folder
    var files = new Folder(smartObject.replaceFolderPath).getFiles();

    //Resize all the image files
    files.forEach(function (file) {

        var doc = app.open(file);

        doc.resizeImage(
            new UnitValue(smartObject.width + ' pixels'),
            new UnitValue(smartObject.height + ' pixels'),
            smartObject.resolution
        );

        //save to temp folder
        doc.saveAs(
            new File(smartObject.tempFolderPath + "/" + file.name),
            new PNGSaveOptions(),
            true
        );

        doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES)
    });

});
```

Finally, replace the smart object

```
//get list of file again
var files = new Folder(smartObject.replaceFolderPath).getFiles();

files.forEach(function(file){

    var fileName = file.name;

    smartObjects.forEach(function(smartObject){

        //active the window opening the smart object
        app.activeDocument = app.documents.getByName(args.documentName);

        var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
        desc.putPath(charIDToTypeID("null"), new File(smartObject.tempFolderPath + "/" + fileName));

        executeAction(stringIDToTypeID( "placedLayerReplaceContents" ), desc, DialogModes.NO);

    });

    //Now export document
    var webOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    webOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG; // SaveDocumentType.JPEG
    webOptions.optimized = true;
    webOptions.quality = 100;

    doc.exportDocument(new File("/path/to/result/folder" + file.name), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, webOptions);

});
```

Now you can close all the opening smart objects

```
smartObjects.forEach(function (s) {
    app.documents.getByName(r.docName).close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using three different methods:

SOLUTION 1) Have a pre-processing step that batch-resizes all of your images, to be the exact size needed to perfectly fit your Smart Objects. You could do this by recording an action which sizes it to those specific dimensions, at the required DPI, then running it as a batch. (If you're not familiar with how to record actions or run batch operations in Photoshop, see [this guide on actions](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/actions-actions-panel.html) and [this guide on batches](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html) from the official Adobe website.) Then after you've pre-processed the images, you'll need to update your code to use the images from whatever output folder those post-resized images ended up in. You should then be able to run this .jsx code to automate the Smart Object batch replacement via Photoshop scripting.

SOLUTION 2) There's a Photoshop plugin called [Batch-Replace Smart Objects](https://exchange.adobe.com/apps/cc/8e3097ba/batch-replace-smart-objects), which automates this process -- and there's also an option you can check which will "Stretch To Fit Smart Objects." The way the plugin works is, you specify your Photoshop document(s) you want to use, the input folder(s) of images, and the output folder(s) to export to. If you select that "Stretch To Fit Smart Objects" option, this will resize all of your images to exactly fit the Smart Object's dimensions. (Note that instead of doing this as a pre-processing step, when you automate this via this plugin, it instead resizes the image in real time as the operations run. Doesn't really matter either way, since the end-result is the same -- the sequence of events is just slightly different using this plugin.) So basically, using this plugin, you can automate the batch Smart Object replacement operations themselves -- but then there's also the option, for each of these operations, to stretch all images to fit the Smart Object's dimensions.

SOLUTION 3) Instead of manually running the batch operations yourselves, you could modify your .jsx code / Photoshop script to actually run the desired batch operations -- but have it do so programmatically, by just coding it into the script. I've used this method when I needed this automated as part of a larger Photoshop workflow, where all of the commands needed to run in sequence. I'd check [the Adobe Community forums](https://community.adobe.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&q=batch%20resize%20images) to see if you can find some guides on how to do this via .jsx code instead of via the Photoshop interface.